# Unable show poup login when I login facebook second times in android

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-login, logout

Here is my code for login in facebook:

```
private boolean isFirstTime;
    private CustomProgressDialog customProgressDialog;
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
    private String fbEmail;
    private String fbName;
    private String fbToken;
    private String id;
    private String avatar;
    private LoginView mView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        isFirstTime = true;

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);

        }
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(
                    Arrays.asList("email", "user_likes", "user_status")));
        }

        mView = new LoginView(this);
        mView.imgLoginFaceBook.setOnClickListener(this);
        mView.rllLoginSkip.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == mView.imgLoginFaceBook) {
            facebookLogin();

        }
        if (v == mView.rllLoginSkip) {
            ReplaceToPage.ReplaceToHome(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

    }

    private void facebookLogin() {

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(this);
            request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
            request.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
            session.openForRead(request.setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void updateFacebookView() {
        final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (isFirstTime) {
            isFirstTime = false;
            return;
        }
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Log.d("access token", session.getAccessToken());
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                // callback after Graph API response with user
                // object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        if (user.asMap().toString().contains("email")) {

                            fbEmail = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
                            fbToken = user.asMap().get("id").toString();
                            Globals.FBToken = fbToken;
                            fbName = user.asMap().get("last_name").toString();
                            Globals.name = user.getName();
                            id = user.getId();
                            String idd = user.getId();
                            avatar = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large";
                            Log.i("avatar", avatar);

                            ACCUtils.setStringPreferences(getApplicationContext(), "", avatar);

                            ReplaceToPage.ReplaceToHome(LoginActivity.this);
                        } else {

                            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                            return;

                        }
                    }
                }

            });

        }
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            updateFacebookView();
        }
    }
```

Here is my code for logout:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (session != null) {
                if (!session.isClosed()) {
                    session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                }
            }

            ACCUtils.setStringPreferences(getApplicationContext(), "", "");
            Globals.FBToken = "";
```

The first login was woking good, but when I logout and login again, it doesn't show popup and allow app login from fb. I want to show popup, help me!!!!